# Let $U$ be a vector hyperplane. Why does this calculation not find a basis for U?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, education

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$ and a generic hyperplane $U = \{(a, b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^4: \lambda_2b + \lambda_3c + \lambda_4d = 0, \lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}  \}$. The task is to find a basis of $U$.

For context I'm currently marking papers of some students in a second year university linear algebra module containing a question very similar to this, except with a specific example. I know like the back of my hand how to do this. Just take a generic vector from $U$, substitute one of the coordinates $b,c$ or $d$ in terms of the other two and after expanding the vector out the three you are left with are a basis.

However, one of the students I'm marking did the following (I'm doing it in terms of the general case I've presented here):
$$ \left(\begin{matrix} a \\ 
b \\ 
c \\ 
d 
\end{matrix}  \right) = \left(\begin{matrix} a \\ -\frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_2}c - \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_2}d \\ -\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_3}b - \frac{\lambda_4}{\lambda_3}d \\ -\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_4}b - \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_4}c \end{matrix}\right) = a\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 
\end{matrix}  \right) + b\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 
0 \\ 
-\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_3} \\ 
-\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_4} 
\end{matrix}  \right)  + c\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 
-\frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_2} \\ 
0 \\ 
-\frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_4} 
\end{matrix}  \right) + d\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 
-\frac{\lambda_4}{\lambda_2} \\ 
-\frac{\lambda_4}{\lambda_3} \\ 
0 
\end{matrix}  \right)
$$
as in, instead of just substituting *one* coordinate it terms of the others, they substituted *all three*, and then went on to show that these four vectors are linearly independent. Which as it turns out is *always* true, and so went on to "show" that $U = \mathbb{R}^4$, which is of course not true, since hyperplanes always have codimension $1$.

The issue is that I'm not entirely sure *why* this is incorrect. If a student were to ask me why this method doesn't work, I wouldn't know what to tell them. So why doesn't this work? And why are these vectors always linearly independent? What is being demonstrated when we show these vectors are linearly independent?

Comment: The vector with coefficient $b$ is not in the hyperplane.

Comment: The four vectors are linearly independent, but the constraint on $b,c,d$ remains, so not ***any*** linear combination of the four vectors is in the hyperplane: which is why it's not four dimensional.

Comment: Got it, thanks guys!

Comment: Basically, when you use an equation to solve for one of its unknowns, and then substitute it into an expression containing that unknown, you can then only forget the equation used only because the unknown solved for has disappeared. What is done here is simultaneous substitution for several unknowns, resulting in an expression that still contains all of them, so that  the equation used cannot be forgotten.